# Теряется заголовок HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: nginx, сеть, ip, wifi

Вопрос не самый тривиальный, но мало ли.

Есть wifi-сеть, роутер Алкатель (не помню какой), изначально доступ в интернет закрыт. Открыты лишь несколько ip. При подключении к сети открывается портал-авторизации, где пользователь должен ввести определенные данные, после чего через RADIUS открывается доступ в интернет. До того момента, как пользователь авторизован, порталу известен его IP через заголовок HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR (серый ip, напр. 10.0.1.141). После авторизации и получения доступа в интернет, при следующем заходе на портал заголовок HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR пропадает, в других заголовках нет серого ip с которым авторизовался этот пользователь.

При этом появляется новый заголовок HTTP_X_REAL_IP (напр 109.194.144.60 похож на DHCP), но там забит новый проксированный ip.

Собсно и вопрос, что делать, чтобы заголовок не терялся при авторизации и почему так происходит, или как получить первоначальный IP имея проксированный?

Конфиги nginx:

```
log_format  v_proxy 'local_time: $time_local;  host: $host;  http_x_real_ip:$http_x_real_ip;  '
                'http_x_forwarded_for:$http_x_forwarded_for; '
                'request: "$request";  status: $status;  body_bytes_sent: $body_bytes_sent;  '
                'http_referer: "$http_referer";  http_user_agent: "$http_user_agent";';


server {
    listen {{ env "CONTAINER_PORT" }};

    root    {{ env "PROJECT_DIR" }}/data;
    add_header X-Backend-Server $hostname;
    add_header X-Project {{ env "PROJECT_NAME" }};

    index index.php;

    port_in_redirect off;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
        }

        {{if env "CI_COMMIT_TAG"}}
            add_header Cache-Control s-maxage=3600;
        {{end}}
    }
}
```

---

```
upstream {{ env "FQDN" }} {
  {{$project_name := env "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" }}
  {{range service $project_name}}server {{.Address}}:{{.Port}} max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60 weight=1;
  {{else}}server 127.0.0.1:65535; # force a 502{{end}}
}


server {
    server_name perm.{{ env "FQDN" }} msk.{{ env "FQDN" }} ekat.{{ env "FQDN" }};
    listen 80;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name perm.{{ env "FQDN" }} msk.{{ env "FQDN" }} ekat.{{ env "FQDN" }};


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://{{ env "FQDN" }};
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    access_log {{env "LOG_DIR" }}/{{env "PROJECT_DIR_SUFFIX"}}/access-ssl.log;
    error_log {{env "LOG_DIR" }}/{{env "PROJECT_DIR_SUFFIX"}}/nginx-error.log info;

}
```

Comment: Я мало что понимаю в написанном (с RADIUS не связывался), но подозреваю, что заголовки добавляет nginx и соответственно всё зависит от конфига nginx, который, возможно, стоит приложить к вопросу

Comment: @andreymal добавил